# proving $|X|<|Y|$, $|Y|<|Z| \Longrightarrow |X|<|Z|$ without CSB

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

how to prove that if $|X|<|Y|$, $|Y|<|Z|$ then $|X|<|Z|$ without CSB theorem?
it is immediate that $|X|\leq |Z|$ so I tried to assume that $|X|=|Z|$ and reach a contradiction but so far I couldn't.

Comment: Could you explain what CSB is? Also, more info about $X, Y, Z$

Comment: by CSB I refer to Cantor - Schröder - Bernstein theorem

Comment: An injection from $Z$ to $X$ would allow you to construct an injection from $Z$ to $Y$, contradicting $|Y|<|Z|$.

Comment: @Ariel I already did this, i.e I found an injection from $Z$ to $Y$. so I guess my real question is how do I reach a contradiction from here without using CSB?

Comment: So how exactly do you define $|X| < |Y|$?

Comment: @user87690 the definition for $|X|<|Y|$ I saw is: $|X|\leq |Y|$ and $|X|\not= |Y|$ where the definition of $|X|\leq |Y|$ is that there is some subset $Z$ of $Y$ such that $|X|=|Z|$

Comment: @user87690 Another standard (and equivalent) definition is that there exists an injection $X \to Y$, but not a bijection.

Comment: @jureslak I agree that your definition is almost the same as mine by using the fact that if $|X|\leq |Y|$ then there exist an injection from $X$ to $Y$, but I still don't see how to reach the contradticion I need.

Comment: But the standard definition makes sense just because of CSB, doesn't it? I would start with the definition of $|X| ≤ |Y|$ using the existence of injective function, observe that it is a preorder, and then define its strict variant in a generic way, i.e. $|X| < |Y|$ if $|X| ≤ |Y|$ and they are not equivalent where the equivalence is induced by the preorder. So if $|X| ≤ |Y|$ but not $|X| ≥ |Y|$. CSB is just noting that the induced equivalence is the same as the bijection existence equivalence.

Comment: @user87690 I see your point and it seems a convenient way to approach it but if I go with this definition of $|X|<|Y|$ then I must prove that it's the same as my definition and I think that the difficulty of trying to detour CSB would still lie there.

Comment: @dorsh605: That's point. CSB is exactly the thing saying that the definitions are the same, so I think you need CSB. But changing the definition as I suggest gives you a way to say more without mentioning CSB. Why are you trying to avoid CSB in the first place?

Comment: @user87690 I'm trying to avoid it because this question appeared before the section of CSB theorem in my course textbook.

Comment: That's why I'd use a general approach: “If $≤$ is a preorder and $<$ is the induced strict variant, then $<$ is a transitive relation”… that holds in general but you need the general definitions of course. I.e. the strict variant is based just on the given preored and not on some other particular equivalence as with your definition.

Comment: @user87690 I guess that satisfy. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'll summarize in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is a matter of definitions.

Let $≤$ be a preorder. We define the induced equivalence by $x \sim y \iff x ≤ y$ and $x ≥ y$. We also define the induced strict variant by $x < y \iff x ≤ y$ and $x \nsim y \iff x ≤ y$ and $x \ngeq y$.

Now we can prove the following general theorem: If $≤$ is a preorder, then $<$ is a strict order (i.e. an antireflexive transitive relation).

In your case, the preorder is $|X| ≤ |Y|$ defined as “there is an injection from $X$ to $Y$”. There is also an equivalence $|X| = |Y|$ defined as “there is a bijection between $X$ and $Y$”. This equivalence is finer than the equivalence induced by the preorder. However, CSB exactly says that they are the same. So if you define $|X| < |Y|$ as the strict variant, you get the result from the general theorem, but if you defined it using the finer equivalence, you need CSB.

In fact, it can be proved that you need CSB. You can prove CSB from your proposition if the definition is based on the finer equivalence. Let $|X| ≤ |Y|$ and $|Y| ≤ |X|$. If there is no bijection between $X$ and $Y$, then $|X| < |Y| < |X|$ so $|X| < |X|$, which is a contradition.